# Fitting column width to text

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}% raggedleft column X
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \label{tbl:unitroot}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{7}{Y}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Confidence Indicators}} \\
        \midrule
        Level & ADF & PP & KPSS& Differenced& ADF& PP& KPSS\\ 
        \hline
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & $\Delta$ Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  & $\Delta$ Retail trade & 360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71& (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  & $\Delta$ Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{7}{Y}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Stock Returns}} \\
        \midrule
        Level & ADF & PP & KPSS& Differenced& ADF& PP& KPSS\\ 
        \hline
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & $\Delta$ Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  & $\Delta$ Retail trade & 360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71& (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  & $\Delta$ Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am interested in fitting the fifth column to its text. Just to look like the first column. I have tried to change some of the `tabularx` parameters but faild to do the desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `tabularx` for numeric tables, it is designed to set the target width for *line breaking* within a cell.

If you just use `tabular` and `r` it all fits, you could improve with `c`  for headings and other small improvements, but simply not using my code is the main improvement you need here,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}% raggedleft column X
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \label{tbl:unitroot}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{r}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Confidence Indicators}} \\
        \midrule
        Level & ADF & PP & KPSS& Differenced& ADF& PP& KPSS\\ 
        \hline
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & $\Delta$ Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  & $\Delta$ Retail trade & 360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71& (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  & $\Delta$ Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
    \end{tabular}


    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{l}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Stock Returns}} \\
        \midrule
        Level & ADF & PP & KPSS& Differenced& ADF& PP& KPSS\\ 
        \hline
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & $\Delta$ Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  & $\Delta$ Retail trade & 360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71& (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  & $\Delta$ Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a table with numeric data, I recommend using `siunitx`. There's no need to artificially widen the table to cover all the textwidth (but you can use the `tabular*` form if you really need this).

The only tricky setting is in the third column, where a format `-2.2` seems better (a minus sign is wider than a digit). The syntax is easy: `-` means a minus sign is present in some row, `2.2` means that the numbers have two digits in the integral part and two in the decimal part. Alignment at the decimal point is automatic. Note also that headers in the S columns must be braced.

I think it's also better to use a single table.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering

\caption{Unit root tests} \label{tbl:unitroot}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  l
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\textit{Level} & {ADF} & {PP} & {KPSS} &
  \textit{Differenced} & {ADF} & {PP} & {KPSS} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Confidence Indicators}} \\
\midrule
Market        & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & $\Delta$ Market        & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Manufacturing & 360 &  -7.33 & 12.63 & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 &   7.33 & 12.63 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Construction  & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43 & $\Delta$ Retail trade  & 360 &   3.40 & 13.84 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Services      & 216 &   3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services      & 216 &   3.99 & 19.19 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Consumer      & 360 &  -9.31 &  8.64 & $\Delta$ Consumer      & 360 &  -9.31 &  8.64 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Stock Returns}} \\
\midrule
Market        & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & $\Delta$ Market        & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Manufacturing & 360 &  -7.33 & 12.63 & $\Delta$ Manufacturing & 360 &   7.33 & 12.63 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Construction  & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43 & $\Delta$ Retail trade  & 360 &   3.40 & 13.84 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Services      & 216 &   3.99 & 19.19 & $\Delta$ Services      & 216 &   3.99 & 19.19 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\addlinespace
Consumer      & 360 &  -9.31 &  8.64 & $\Delta$ Consumer      & 360 &  -9.31 &  8.64 \\
(p-value)     & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & (p-value)              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would remove one column from the table entirely, and I would restructure the header so as to make clear to the reader how the report's tests are organized. I would also use the `dcolumn` package to align the numeric entries on the respective decimal points. To make the tabular material span the width of the text block, consider using a `tabular*` environment.

Aside: As a time series econometrician, I immediately noticed that the "P" in "KPSS", as well as the first "P" in "PP", denote the first initial of my doctoral adviser's name -- "Phillips". :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb!]
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \label{tbl:unitroot}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}
           l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c *{2}{d{3.2}} c *{2}{d{3.2}} @{} }
        \toprule
        Variable & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Differenced}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}
        & \mc{ADF} & \mc{PP} & \mc{KPSS} 
        & \mc{ADF} & \mc{PP} & \mc{KPSS}\\ 
        \midrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Confidence Indicators}} \\[0.5ex]
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  &  360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  &  360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71&  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 &  216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  &  360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\[2ex]
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Stock Returns}} \\[0.5ex]
        Market & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\ 
        Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.63  &  360 & 7.33 & 12.63  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\
        Construction & 360 & -17.23 & 23.43  &  360 & 3.40 & 13.84 \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71&  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Services  & 216 & 3.99 & 19.19 &  216 & 3.99 & 19.19  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71  &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        Consumer & 360 & -9.31 & 8.64  &  360 & -9.31 & 8.64  \\
        (p-value) & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 &  360 & 101.77 & 10.71  \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a better structure.